# Cannot update simperium user from localhost:8000

Tags: javascript, cors, simperium

I'm using Simperium JS in Safari, and have been able to authenicate, and fetch data from buckets with no problems at all. I am even able to create new users.

However, when I try to use the `<rest-of-url>/update/` calls when running locally on a server, I get cross-origin request issues. It appears that the Simperium server is rejecting requests from `http://localhost:8000`, as I can load up an HTML file (using a `file://` url), and the request succeeds.

Is this an intentional thing, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`auth.simperium.com/1/.../update/`](https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#update) call has been updated to support cross origin requests so you should be able to use that now. The `reset_password` and `delete` endpoints though probably won't be since they require use of an API key with admin privileges.